# Reflection principles

Tags: lo.logic

Let con(ZFC) be a sentence in ZFC asserting that ZFC has an omega-model M. Let  $A_{M}$  be an wff over M. Let S be the theory ZFC+con(ZFC). Is the reflection for S: $Bew_{S}(A_{M}) \implies A_{M}$ is satisfied?
 I asking also for an explanation of the paradox in the link

http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2007-October/012035.html

of the case when ZFC is replaced on  S=ZFC+(ZFC has  omega-model)?

Comment: Could you explain what does $Bew_S(A_M)$ mean? Also, perhaps you could re-word your final question somehow; I don't really understand it as it is written. 

Comment: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2007-October/012035.html

Comment: I don't know what Bew_S(A) means here. Are you asking for an explanation of the paradox in the link you mention? 

Comment: Bew_{S}(A_M) mean that A_M is provable in S.

Comment: Joel, I think Bew_S(A_M) is supposed to be (a formalization of) the statement that A_M is provable in S. ("Bew" was, I believe, used by Gödel to abbreviate "beweisbar".)

Comment: Of course Bew_S(X)--->X is true for any X, because all the axioms of S are true.  But that argument uses information that goes beyond ZFC, so presumably the question should be whether Bew_S(A_M)--->A_M is provable in some (yet to be specified) formal system.  It should also be explained what is meant by a wff being "over M" and in particular why such a wff is in the language of S so that Bew_S(A_M) makes sense.

Comment: I am with Andreas in his interpretation; and I suspect that the phrase "is satisfied" at the end of the question was meant to be "is satisfied in M$. In this reading, the answer is clearly YES.

Comment:  wff being "over M" meant an wff with bounded quantifiers restrict by M. 

Comment:  jdh.hamkins.org I asking also for an explanation of the paradox in the link http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2007-October/012035.html
of the case S=ZFC+ omega-model? 

Comment: I am interested in a very specific reflection principle, and would like to understand this question.  Please, could you please explain the meaning of Bew_{S}(A_M) --> A_M? What are the definitions of "Bew" and "A_M"?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to note the reflection principle mentioned by Jaykov is actually a schema; there is such a conditional for every sentence $\phi$ in the formal language being used. Further, the intuitive reading for each individual member of the scheme is something like "If S proves $\Phi$ then $\Phi$ is true (or $\Phi$ holds, or whatever variation you prefer)". For arbitrary $\Phi$ this is known as the Uniform Reflection Principle for S. Feferman (Turing, Beklemishev, Smorynski and others) have shown that there are all kinds of subtleties involving these proof-theoretic reflection 

Comment: principles. For example, there really is no "good" formalization of "is provable" in the sense that there are lots of non-standard proof predicates that can be constructed and there is no mathematical distinction between the non-standard and standard proof predicates. There is also ambiguity in the sentence(s) formalizing that S is a consistent theory (or has a model, or has an omega-model, etc.). There is an excellent article (and also a book) by Torkel Franzen. Smorynski's article in the Handbook of Mathematical Logic is also a good place to start. I can provide lots more info/literature if 

Comment: Erin, I'm curious about the specific reflection principle you're interested in. It seems you are interested primarily in set theory so it may very well be the case that you are interested in a set-theoretic reflection principle as opposed to a proof-theoretic principle. Proof-theoretic principles are typically formalized versions of the intuition that a particular proof-system or set of axioms is sound. Set-theoretic reflection principles seem to express the intuition that certain kinds of structure in V keep repeating or reflecting arbitrarily high up in the cumulative hierarchy.  

Comment: Thanks for clarifying which type of reflection principle this question asks about, and sorry for the redundant comment, I didn't understand some of the comments before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the "paradox" you're asking about is the passage marked with >> at the link you gave, but with "$\omega$-model" in place of "model" and with "has an $\omega$-model" in place of "is consistent".  But then there is no longer any justification for the statement (on lines 9 & 10) that there's a proof in ZFC of the negation of con(ZFC) (which now becomes the negation of "ZFC has an $\omega$-model").  What you have is rather that this negation holds in all $\omega$-models of ZFC, but that doesn't immediately translate into a syntactic fact about existence of a proof, which you could then translate into English.

I conjecture that, if you write down carefully just what the "paradox" is supposed to be, it will disappear.